# Comparar variável mais de uma vez, sem repeti-la

Tags: php

#### Exemplo:

Tenho **uma variável**, que pode ser valor **entre 1 e 10**.

**Faço as comparações/condições** para imprimir o resultado.

```
$var = 5;

if ($var == 1) echo 'A';
else if ($var == 2 || $var == 6) echo 'B';
else if ($var == 3 || $var == 5) echo 'C';
else if ($var == 4) echo 'D';
else echo 'X';

//Saída: C
```

Se eu fizer da seguinte forma:

```
if ($var == 1) echo 'A';
else if ($var == (2 || 6)) echo 'B';
...
```

**Sempre** irá imprimir `B`.

---

#### Dúvidas:

- Por que sempre irá cair nessa condição? (`(2 || 6)` = 1 = true? Em vista, sim, está incorreta a condição)
- Existe uma forma de **verificar vários valores possíveis** sem precisar ficar repetindo a condição 2x ou mais (`($var == 2 || $var == 6)`)? (tipo um `IN` em linguagem SQL)

Comment: Tipo `in_array($var, [2, 6])`?

Comment: Exatamente o que o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse, ou se sua versão do PHP for antes do PHP7: `if(in_array($var, array(2,6)) echo 'B';`

Comment: @DavidAlves essa sintaxe existe desde a versão 5.4 do PHP.

Comment: Hmm, obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu achei que tinha sido implementada junto do PHP7

Comment: Acabei de testar. Funcionando na 5.6!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível sim fazer o que você quer utilizando a função [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Ficando assim versões PHP5.4+

```
$var = 5;

if ($var == 1) echo 'A';
else if (in_array($var, [2,6])) echo 'B';
else if (in_array($var, [3,5])) echo 'C';
else if ($var == 4) echo 'D';
else echo 'X';

//Saída: C
```

Ou assim em versões PHP5.3-

```
$var = 5;

if ($var == 1) echo 'A';
else if (in_array($var, array(2,6))) echo 'B';
else if (in_array($var, array(3,5))) echo 'C';
else if ($var == 4) echo 'D';
else echo 'X';

//Saída: C
```